# How to reload a specific cell with out animation in swift 3?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I am trying to like a post in a tableview, after getting response i need to update like status in my tableview without knowing to user that table is reloading.

```
 let indexPath = IndexPath(item: tag, section: 0)
 self.tableCommunity.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
```

Comment: Try self.tableCommunity.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)

Comment: Thanks its working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

buddy try using code :-

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(item: tag, section: 0)
self.tableCommunity.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
```

Hope it will work.